# VBA macro to save excel file using path from cell in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a sheet TDadosRecTransf from ModStatRec.xlsm to a new file that I want to save as TDadosRecTransf.xlsx.
I want that the path to save the file TDadosRecTransf.xlsx be a text value in cell A9 of sheet "Instrucoes" in ModStatRec.xlsm in substitution of "C:\Transfer\Receitas\"that I have now.

I have the following code

```
Sheets("TDadosRecTransf").Select
Sheets("TDadosRecTransf").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Transfer\Receitas\TDadosRecTransf.txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

I tried to setup a Variable in the top of code like this

```
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = Workbooks("ModStatRec.xlsm").Worksheets("Instrucoes").Range("A29").Value
```

and the line

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Filepath" & "\TDadosRecTransf.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I get this done? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Drop the **double quotes**

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Filepath & "\TDadosRecTransf.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```